# How to turn vibrate on and keep sound on as well

Tags: android, audio, vibration, android-audiomanager

Since `AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE` also silences the device, how do you turn on vibrate and keep the current volume level (e.g. if there's an incoming call the phone will vibrate AND play the ring tone)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to use:

```
setVibrateSetting(AudioManagerVIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
```

Although the method was deprecated in API 16, I don't know a good replacement for it if you're looking to change the vibrate settings for more than your own app.

Just make sure that the ringer mode is on `AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL` as well.

---

Of course, you could also just set the ringer mode to `AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL` and bring up the settings page for the user to change the vibrate setting manually.

Answer (score 0):

Review this code,

```
// Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
        Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        // Start immediately
        // Vibrate for 200 milliseconds
        // Sleep for 500 milliseconds
        long[] pattern = { 0, 200, -1 };

        // The "0" means to repeat the pattern starting at the beginning
        // CUIDADO: If you start at the wrong index (e.g., 1) then your
        // pattern
        // will be off --
        // You will vibrate for your pause times and pause for your vibrate
        // times !
        vb.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```

to stop, call

```
vb.cancel();
```

Note: 
vb.cancel() should not be called immediately after vb.vibrate(pattern, 0);

Comment: I don't think the question was "How do I make it vibrate now?"